Contador incremental de 10 dígitos en Ensamblador
Soy nuevo en este lenguaje y estoy aprendiendo lo básico. Necesito programar un contador incremental de 10 dígitos utilizando instrucciones de bajo nivel como MOV, INC, DEC, AND, OR, JMP, JZ, JNZ, etc. No se pueden usar funciones de alto nivel como DB.
El simulador que utilizo es este: https://schweigi.github.io/assembler-simulator/
Por ahora tengo este código de un contador de 2 dígitos.
Una duda especifica es que debo de tener en cuenta para no ocupar toda la memoria ya que es un error común al realizar este contador.
MOV A, 0xE8
MOV B,0x30
MOV [A], B
INC A
MOV B,0x30
INICIO:
MOV [A], B
INC B
CMP B, 0x3A
JNZ INICIO
DEC A
MOV B, [A]
INC B
MOV [A], B
MOV B, 0x30
INC A 

JMP INICIO


Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! y cual seria el problema?
